# Symfony GoogleAuth + Json_Login

Tags: authentication, symfony, authorization, google-oauth

How to use GoogleAuthenticator and Json_login together in Symphony Firewall?

I try make it separate and in same main firewall

```
security:
    firewalls:
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            provider: app_user_provider
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api_sign_in
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
            logout:
                path: /api_logout
                target: /

        main:
           
            provider: app_user_provider
            
            entry_point: App\Security\Socials\GoogleAuthenticator
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\Socials\GoogleAuthenticator
```

But not help, app every time try use GoogleAuthenticator

Thank you!

Comment: You default authneticator (main) is GoogleAuthenticator. For using API login use path -> /api_sign_in

Comment: So for GoogleAuthenticator need make other pattern path?